# read image details(GPS long lat) from data_URL

Tags: c#, cordova, android-camera, exif, exiflib

i have use cordova phonegap api for open a camera

```
        $scope.capturePhoto = function () {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: 1});
        }
        $scope.capturePhotoEdit = function () {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: 1});
        }
        $scope.getPhoto = function () {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: 0});
        }
        $scope.getPhotoAlbum = function () {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: 2});
        }
        onFail = function (message) {
            $window.alert(message);
        }
```

In DATA_URL long string like base64 but image details not read by exif in C#

if i have use File upload and convert into base64 then easily get the Exif details(GPS Long Lat) in C#, but not open a camera with File uploader tag :

```
 function readImage(input) {
    console.log(input);
        if ( input.files && input.files[0] ) {
           var FR= new FileReader();
           FR.onload = function(e) {
            // $('#img').attr( "src", e.target.result );
             $('#base').text( e.target.result );
           };       
         FR.readAsDataURL( input.files[0] );
       }
    }

   $("#asd").change(function(){
         readImage( this );
   });
```

Read Exif details in c# code is:

```
using ExifLibrary;

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(model.imagebase64);
            string file = model.workId + "_" + SnapName + ".Jpeg";
            string liveserverpath =        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyFileLocation"].ToString();
            liveserverpath = liveserverpath + file;
            var exif = ExifFile.Read(liveserverpath);
            try
            {
                newmodel.P_Latitude = (exif.Properties[ExifTag.GPSLatitude]).ToString();
                newmodel.P_Longitude = (exif.Properties[ExifTag.GPSLongitude]).ToString();
                newmodel.Snap_Status = "Valid";
            }
```

My Question is that: Why image details are missing in Data_URL(string) and in file upload image to base64 easily read image details(GPS long lat)

please let me know, help me , i had spend a week in that but didn't get any exif image details from data_URL,

Comment: Is it only the GPS data which is missing, or all EXIF data? If it's just the GPS, it's probably a timing issue. I know that on Windows Phone, the GPS data is added some time after the photo is taken (as soon as the phone can obtain a GPS signal). It's probably the same thing happening here.

Comment: missing all exif details in Data_url

Answer (score 0):

This was a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1285) in Cordova versions prior to 2.6.0. If you make sure you're using the latest version of Cordova, you should be OK.

Comment: i have updated cordova with command `cordova platform update android`, face same issue no any kind of exif detail in data_url

Comment: So what version of Cordova _are_ you running?